# Using jetpack Navigation component transition-animation is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-components, navigation-architecture

I am using the jetpack navigation component for the navigation of fragments, I created an anim  at res directory and added this `animation-transition`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="600"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
 </set>
```

and set this animation as enter animation for the fragment opening at navigation component visually:
[image]

after calling this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.reg2Fragment)
```

I am still not getting my manual animation the default fade in and out is showing there.

I am using Material Io design for my whole project theme. and here are my dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

// for Jet-Pack-Navigation-Component
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx'
```

here is the navGraph:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/reg1Fragment">
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/reg1Fragment"
    android:name="com.example.authapp.uiRegistration.Reg1Fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_reg1"
    android:label="Reg1Fragment" >
        <action
        android:id="@+id/action_reg1Fragment2_to_reg2Fragment"
        app:destination="@id/reg2Fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/reg2Fragment"
    android:name="com.example.authapp.uiRegistration.Reg2Fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_reg2"
    android:label="Reg2Fragment" >
        <action
        android:id="@+id/action_reg2Fragment_to_reg3Fragment"
        app:destination="@id/reg3Fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/reg3Fragment"
    android:name="com.example.authapp.uiRegistration.Reg3Fragment"
    android:label="fragment_reg3"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_reg3" >
       <action
        android:id="@+id/action_reg3Fragment_to_userProfile"
        app:destination="@id/userProfile"
        app:popUpTo="@id/userProfile" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
    android:id="@+id/userProfile"
    android:name="com.example.authapp.UserProfile"
    android:label="activity_user_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_user_profile" />
    </navigation>
```

Any expert please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the navGraph specifically for the related part

Comment: I updated the question please check the navGraph XML

Comment: sorry just updated as the editor not accepting the copy paste, so arrange that, thanks.

Comment: You may increase  the fragment transaction duration time to check whether it works

Comment: Tausif I did from 600 to 2000 android:duration="2000" still nothing showing the default fade in is showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `findNavController().navigate(R.id.reg2Fragment)`

Here [the version of the `navigate(destinationId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(kotlin.Int)) method doesn't involve the animation as the `R.id.reg2Fragment` doesn't provide any information more than the destination fragment id.

But in order to include the animation in the navigation, you need to use the [navigate() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(androidx.navigation.NavDirections)) that accepts a `navDirection` argument which is typically the method of the generated Direction class for this particular action.

So, as the id of the `action` is `action_reg1Fragment2_to_reg2Fragment`:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_reg1Fragment2_to_reg2Fragment"
    app:destination="@id/reg2Fragment"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
```

Then, the navigation would be:

`findNavController().navigate(Reg1FragmentDirections.actionReg1Fragment2ToReg2Fragment())`

Comment: Wow! it did work, thank you, sir, I really appreciate your time.